# SWIG rename functions

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I am using following code in an interface file to rename the global function `free`

```
%ignore free;
%rename(my_free) free;
```

But resultant header file I don't see any of `free` is renamed to `my_free`. Am I doing anything 
wrong here? The above lines are placed at top of the interface file means first and second line respectively. I saw this [here](http://binf.gmu.edu/software/SWIG/SWIGPlus.html#ambiguity_resolution_renaming).

Answer (score 1):

The example you showed seems to work exactly as you'd expect. For example given:

```
%module test

%ignore free;
%rename(my_free) free;

// Function declaration:
void free();
// Or use %include if you prefer
```

Running:

```
swig -Wall -java test.i
```

Generates test.java as:

```
public class test {
  public static void my_free() {
    testJNI.my_free();
  }
}
```

So it has been renamed as expected.

Actually the `%ignore` is entirely redundant here though, the `%rename` alone would be sufficient to achieve this result. The order is important though - the `%rename` supersedes the `%ignore` and both must be before the declaration of `free` is seen.

The official documentation is at [swig.org](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#ambiguity_resolution_renaming), I'd tend to prefer that over other sites. (If you're [using SWIG 2.0 there's a lot of extra features for renaming too](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_rename_ignore) and you can use `%rename` to ignore functions: `%rename("$ignore") free;`)